# Sharing and Permissions - always shows "Fetching" instead of the user name

Tags: external-disk, permission, spotlight, nas

I am a basic Mac user, so please bear with me.
I have a WD MyCloud EX2 to store large files and videos - over 10000 files, so searching is critical for me. The WD NAS, the iMac are connected via ethernet cables to a simple TPLink network switch and the internet - all works fine.
I can access/open/play any file stored on the WD NAS - no problem.
I can see all the filenames when I open the folder...

When use Spotlight search, no files stored on the WD NAS are ever displayed in the results. For example if I search for 'holiday 12.mp4' - a file that I can see in the folder, the search returns 0 results.

Spotlight search works for files on my iMac, so spotlight is working.

Investigating further, I opened the 'Get Info' file for 'holiday 12.mp4' - in the sharing & permissions section it shows 'Fetching" next the icon for administrator. All files on stored on the external NAS show this. All files stored on the iMac show the correct administrator name.

There is no 'lock' button in the sharing and permissions folder of files stored on the WD drive, allowing me to change this setting. There is on any file which is stored locally on the iMac.

Finally if I look at a file stored on the iMac - where I can see the Admin name, and I can search normally... and move this same file to the WD drive, in sharing and permissions, the Admin changes to 'fetching' and I can no longer search for the file.

Maybe the two issues are not linked, maybe they are - all (simple) advice welcome. Thank You.

Comment: The Mac loses control of permissions as soon as the file is sent to the NAS, which has its own operating system & file permissions, however simple. You'd probably have to check the NAS's manual for how it assigns & handles permissions.